# SQL join on 3 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get data from 3 different tables. I need to get code and lengte from table cursussen, begindatum form table uitvoeringen, naam and voorl form table medewerkers.

The tables: columns are ->

```
- uitvoeringen: cursus, begindatum, docent, locatie
- cursussen: code, omschrijving, type, lengte 
- medewerkers: mnr, naam, voorl, gbdatum
```

(medewerkers.mnr is the same as uitvoeringen.docent and cursussen.code is the same uitvoeringen.cursus)

I have tried using inner joins like i read on different websites including stackoverflow but i keep getting

> "ORA-00904: "UITOERINGEN"."DOCENT": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 7 Column: 22"

Here is the query i wrote. And yes, this is homework for school but i really can't solve this. I looked on tons of websites but it didn't help.

```
SELECT cursussen.code, cursussen.lengte, uitvoeringen.begindatum, 
naam.medewerkers, voorl.medewerkers
FROM uitvoeringen
INNER JOIN cursussen
ON uitvoeringen.cursus = cursussen.code
INNER JOIN uitvoeringen
ON uitvoeringen.docent = medewerkers.mnr;
```

This only my 2nd or 3rd question on here so if i made some mistakes please let me know for next time and thanks in advance.

Heres the data of one of the table uitvoeringen and also it's structure:
[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUWLw.png)

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgkA6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT cursussen.code, cursussen.lengte, uitvoeringen.begindatum, 
medewerkers.naam, medewerkers.voorl
FROM uitvoeringen
INNER JOIN cursussen
ON uitvoeringen.cursus = cursussen.code
INNER JOIN medewerkers
ON uitvoeringen.docent = medewerkers.mnr;
```

Comment: That's how i tried it first, but then i get: 
ORA-00904: "VOORL"."MEDEWERKERS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 85

Comment: Can you share sample data and table structure? What RDMS are you using?

Comment: Yes, i have added it to the OP.

Comment: @Gerizoo your error mentions `"VOORL"."MEDEWERKERS"` which is wrong, change it to `medewerkers.voorl` just like the code in this answer.

Comment: damn i feel so dumb now, the first identifiers were good and then for some reason my brain decided to switch it up. But thanks! It's working now.